# Apache HTTP Client throws NoHttpResponseException When Nginx Ingress Reloaded for POST

Tags: java, apache, nginx, proxy, kubernetes

When we reload the Nginx Ingress config, we get the  `NoHttpResponseException` for some of our POST requests. This does not occur in neither OkHttp client or just plain `ab -c 100 -n 1000 https://...`

Using 4.5.7, the latest one, and disabled the Gzip compression for visibility. Put a break point in `DefaultHttpResponseParser` in:

```
    @Override
    protected HttpResponse parseHead(
            final SessionInputBuffer sessionBuffer) throws IOException, HttpException {
        //read out the HTTP status string
        int count = 0;
        ParserCursor cursor = null;
        do {
            // clear the buffer
            this.lineBuf.clear();
            final int i = sessionBuffer.readLine(this.lineBuf);
            if (i == -1 && count == 0) {
                // The server just dropped connection on us
                throw new NoHttpResponseException("The target server failed to respond");
            }
```

When an error occurs, we observe the buffer has the following contents:

```
0

1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.5
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 08:51:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

10
{"success":true}
```

But for the regular requests, it has the following contents, which makes more sense:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.5
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 08:52:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

10
{"success":true}
```

Now, I am not sure what is wrong, because both okhttp and ab works correctly. Tried many versions, but it seems to remain.